# Vertical line between two div limited height

Tags: html, css

I am trying vertical line between two `div`s. But I don't want it to have the same height as the `div`s.
I need let's say 10% cut from top and 10% cut from bottom.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.line {
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #cfc7c0;
}
.first {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
}
.second {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first line">this is first div and some text</div>
  <div class="second">
    Right
    <br/>and more
    <br/>Side
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VKqEU/124/

Kindly suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try using an `::after` pseudo element.

```css
.line {
    position: relative;
}
.line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #cfc7c0;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.line {
    padding-right: 21px; /* 20+1 */
    position: relative;
}
.line:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #cfc7c0;
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
}
.first {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
}
.second {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first line">this is first div and some text</div>
    <div class="second">
        Right
        <br/>and more
        <br/>Side
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you need to add some padding to .container: http://jsfiddle.net/VKqEU/127/

`.container{
        display : table;
        border : 1px solid blue;
        padding: 10% 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
   display : table;
    border : 1px solid blue;
    height:150px;
}

.line:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    height:120px;
    border-right: 2px dotted #ff0000;
}
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/VKqEU/135/